# Nodejs azure function app Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ipaddress:443

Tags: node.js, azure, axios, azure-function-app

```
I am trying to do http call using axios in node azure function app and **sometimes** I get ETIMEDOUT error. The timeout duration is less than what's set.

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 'ip address of endpoint':443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:129:14)

const axios = require('axios');
const axoisInstance = axios.create({baseURL: myurl});
axoisInstance.defaults.headers.get['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axoisInstance.defaults.timeout = 120000;

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
   axoisInstance.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
   let response = await axoisInstance.get(getURL); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I test with same code with yours, it works fine in my side. The line of code `axoisInstance.defaults.timeout = 120000;` is valid. So it is most likely a server side timeout which is set less than 2min.

If the error was caused by client timeout which you set in the code `axoisInstance.defaults.timeout = 120000;`, it will show error like `Exception: Error: timeout of 120000ms exceeded` (I test with set 60000 timeout and provide the screenshot below). But your error message is `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 'ip address of endpoint':443`.
[image]

Comment: You are right. It's the server timing out.

Comment: @VivekRanjan Thanks for your vote up, could you please also [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) my answer as "accepted", thanks.